# javascript change table rows background color dynamically for setinterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I change the background of rows to dynamically for setinterval but not working.

if clicked the button, change class name as the rows in the table.

My codes:

**HTML Code:**

```
<table id="table">
<tr>
    <td>AAA11</td>
    <td>BBB11</td>
</tr>
..
..
</table>
<button id="btn">click</button>
```

**CSS Codes**

```
.red { background-color: red; }
```

**JS Codes**

```
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

//  My func
function func(){
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var index=0;
        var c = rows[i].className;
            if(c!="red") {
                index=i;
            } else {
            index = i+1;
            }
        sec(index);
    } 
    setInterval(func(), 2000);   
}
// Change class name the rows 
function sec(index){
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        if(index==i) {            
            rows[index].className="red";
        } 
        if(index!=i ){
            rows[index].className="null";
        }
    }
}

$('#btn').click(function(){
    setInterval(func(), 2000); 
});
```

Comment: `setInterval(func, 2000);`

Comment: Not working. the last row is selected.

Comment: or `setInterval("func()", 2000);` (with quotes)

Comment: @Ertbihal when you click on #btn, you should just call the function, not setting interval which is already set inside func(), or do the opposite, or... It's hard to get the logic associated to your code, and ya, using your code, you are just selecting the last row each time by deselecting others, so what do you expect???

Comment: What with user click button many times? Currently the animation will speed up with each click... Probably you want to remove button after click or clear interval each time it happen...

Answer (score 1):

you reset all other lines, except the last row with in the "sec" function.

```
if(index!=i ){
    rows[index].className="null";
}
```

delete that part and it should work like you wanted

...tough i don't get what you want to do, since all you're doing is setting all rows backgrounds...if you want to reset the red ones, don't use your sec() function...try this instead:

```
function func(){
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var index=0;
        var c = rows[i].className;
        if(c=="red") {
            rows[i].className="";
        } else {
            rows[i].className="red";
        }
    } 
}
```

[edit]
...after it's cleared what OP wanted to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/bzWV2/1/

[edit2]
...easier approach:
http://jsfiddle.net/bzWV2/2/

Comment: uh...that's something entirely else than what you did

Comment: this is work only first two row. Multiple row is not working.

Comment: To be universal your second fiddle should be with this if:   `if(i==index%rows.length){` - without hardcoded `3`

Comment: well, since it works, you should consider voting the answer, and maybe accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function highlight(element)
{
    $('tr').removeClass('red');

    el = (!element)? $('tr:first') : element;
    el.addClass('red');
    next_el = el.next('tr');
    var el = (next_el.length == 0)? $('tr:first'): next_el;
    setTimeout(function(){ highlight(el) }, 1000);
}

setTimeout(function(){ highlight() }, 1000);
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/TFcUS/2/

Comment: I want to do as an example. This is a different. [link]http://oi39.tinypic.com/fd7uwh.jpg[/link]

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
var $table = $("#table");
var $rows = $table.find("tr");    
var func = function(){
        var curIndex = $rows.filter('.red').index(),
            nextIndex = curIndex === $rows.length - 1?0:++curIndex;
        $rows.eq(nextIndex).addClass('red').siblings().removeClass('red');
    }


    $('#btn').click(function(){
        $rows.eq(0).addClass('red');
        setInterval(func, 2000); 
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YdErg/)